# SFML trying to get a sprite to track mouse

Tags: c++, sfml

the below code doesn't seem to work I get a very strange sprite that sometimes tracks the mouse but almost gets bored and gives up. If this is the wrong place and need to go to maths exchange.

It seems to do something the sprite wiggles but doesn't follow the mouse and seems based on angle. The /2 is because the sprites position is in centre of screen and m_Resolution is the screen size and I've tried removing it. I didn't know if something was overflowing.

```
float angle = (atan2(mousePosition.y - m_Resolution.y/2,
    mousePosition.x - m_Resolution.x/2)
    * 180.)/ 3.14159;
m_Sprite.setRotation(angle);
```

I've tried for a while I've seen similar questions but my answer seems to match so unsure.

Comment: why you dividing  m_Resolution by two? Why you searching collinear vector betwwen  screen  and mouse?

Comment: that's the screen size the location of the object tracking from is in middle of screen hence screen X/Y divided by 2 equals sprite location. I detailed that in question.

Comment: but maaan, I will say it again, but if you want to rotate sprite to the side of cursor, you need to calulate collinear vectors betweeen sprite and mouse as I did

Comment: try it and u will find my answer correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If was writing your code, I did it like  this:

```
float dX = mousePosition.x - sprite.x;//vector, collinear straight line whicn crosses sprite an cursor on X axis;
float dY = mousePosition.y - sprite.y;//same, but to Y axis;

float angle = (atan2(dY, dX)*180)/3.14159;//CALCULATING ANGLE
sprite.setRotation(angle + 90);
```